# Connecting Cloud firestore database from cross platform xamarin project

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin cross-platform solution containing 4 projects.

1. Android project
2. iOS project
3. UWP Project and
4. Standard library.

I want CRUD operations on Cloud fire-store database.
UWP project working as expected.

But In case of Android project gives error on line in Library project

```
Firestore = FirestoreDb.Create("...-4c982");
```

stating error

> System.InvalidOperationException Message=Error reading credential file from location appointments.json: Could not find file "/....json" Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

A small cross platform project reading/writing to/From cloud firestore will be helpful to me.

Comment: Before initializing the Cloud Firestore, we need to set up the development environment. Please make sure you've added the required dependencies and client libraries to your app. Check the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment

Comment: Replace **PATH** with the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. After setting the environment variable, try to vertify the authentication. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#c), you need to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable in your development environment to point to a JSON service account key file.

You can create that JSON file by going to the [API Console Credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/apis/credentials) and following these steps:

1- Select the Service Account that you are using on the Service Accounts Table to check it's details.

2- In the details page click on the **Add Key** Button and select the **Create New Key** option.

3- Select the JSON Format and confirm, the download of the JSON file will start automatically.

Once you point your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the directory of the JSON file the error will no longer appear.

Comment: Sorry, I have gone through these steps, but could not solve the problem.